# jquery ui slider - issues with using variable to set max

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jquery ui slider, i'm using a variable for the max step of the slider. The problem is the slider loads before the variable is computed, when page loads for the first time, so the slider is buggy - it does not recognize the max number of steps.

Do i need to find a better place in the code to compute the max variable? or is there a better option to fix this problem?

Code below:

```
   $("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: slider_max,
    step: 1, 
    slide: function (event, ui) {
           some code----
    });
```

slider_max = sorted_effective_date.length - 1; --- computed when page loads

The slider works fine after the page has been loaded the first time and the variable has been cached.

Comment: Where/how are you computing the `slider_max` variable?

Comment: You're telling us the problem is whith the computing of the variable, yet you're showing us something completely different ?

Comment: slider_max = sorted_effective_date.length - 1;
it is computer when the page loads